# Creating Custom Map based on User Input

Tags: ios, maps

I'm trying to create a campus navigation app for my college, and in order to do so I need to make a custom map (or use Apple's, but I'd rather make my own), how exactly would I go about it? I had an idea to just use my location and walk around, forcing my phone to draw the map for me (using lines and such) but I wasn't sure how to go about it.

Is there anyway to create a map that updates automatically when new routes are added via anyone's phone? Almost like a collaborative map?

Comment: I would seriously recommend using [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/). It's an alternative to Apple and Google Maps. You can create custom maps with their editor and the code is very similar to Apple's own MapKit.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it!